# Searching/Filtering my own answers

Tags: feature-request, answers, profile-page

I get that you can use the search box at the top for this, probably.
But then you'd need to know how to set that search query up.

It would be helpful if you under your [answers page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/929999/torxed?tab=answers) could filter/search through your X number of answers for a term. it would be less of a learning curve and would be more intuitive.

Until posting this I actually had no idea even that you could (cleverly enough) search through these answers with the top search box. I know I could search tags and similar things. And that's my point.. well two points.. and those are that either I'm stupid or this could be more intuitive.

[image]

Anyway, it's just an idea and hopefully it's not to frowned upon. It's my first and only suggestion of a change to the community. Love SO in all other ways :)

Answer (score 4):

Not a bad idea, but the help you wish for is *actually there*.

Navigate to [[SE site of your choice]/search](https://stackoverflow.com/search) and click on **Advanced Search Tips** on the right, which offers you lots of tips for searching, including finding your own answers easily.

The two flags you need to use in this case are `user:me` and `is:answer`.

Comment: Indeed, as I pointed out it is possible to use the existing search features for sure. And good that you pointed out how in case others search and end up here. Completely forgot to mention this haha.